# how to pick record from a query that has distinct and use of case in sql

Tags: sql, case, distinct

I have a query that i want to pick employee pin no,Employees SurName,Basic_Pay,House_Allowance and transport where the payrollcode matches code say 'P137' for our example.

```
Select distinct Employees.PINNo, 
                Employees.SurName + ' ' + Employees.OtherNames,
                tblEmployeePeriodDetails.Basic_Pay,
                tblEmployeePeriodDetails.House_Allowance,
                transport_Allowance=(case tblPayrollCode.PayrollCode_Code 
                                         when 'P137' then tblEmployeeTransactions.Amount
                                     end)
From Employees Inner Join 
     tblEmployeePeriodDetails On Employees.EmployeeID = tblEmployeePeriodDetails.Employee_ID Inner Join 
     tblEmployeeTransactions On tblEmployeePeriodDetails.Employee_ID = tblEmployeeTransactions.Employee_ID And tblEmployeePeriodDetails.Period_Month = tblEmployeeTransactions.Period_Month And tblEmployeePeriodDetails.Period_Year = tblEmployeeTransactions.Period_Year Inner Join 
     tblPayrollCode On tblEmployeeTransactions.PayrollCode_ID = tblPayrollCode.PayrollCode_ID 
where tblEmployeeTransactions.Period_Month = 7 
      and tblEmployeeTransactions.Period_Year = 2010
```

As per now the query gives me a row where the transport matches the payrollcode and another with transport as 0.I dont want that row in my data.How do I do this?

here is an image of result
[image]

note the highlighted row is the one with value matching transport and the one with 0

Comment: Try not to use select distinct. You should be able to select an employee using a primary key like by there Pin No.
Select distinct can hide problems

Comment: In this case I need all the unique data not by employee but all employees @Bobby

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? The non-standard `+` looks like SQL Server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with subselect:

```
Select 
  Employees.PINNo, 
  Employees.SurName + ' ' + Employees.OtherNames,
  tblEmployeePeriodDetails.Basic_Pay,
  tblEmployeePeriodDetails.House_Allowance,
  transport_Allowance=
    ISNULL((
      select SUM(tblEmployeeTransactions.Amount) 
      from tblEmployeeTransactions Inner Join tblPayrollCode On tblEmployeeTransactions.PayrollCode_ID = tblPayrollCode.PayrollCode_ID 
      where PayrollCode_Code = 'P137' 
        And tblEmployeePeriodDetails.Employee_ID = tblEmployeeTransactions.Employee_ID 
        And tblEmployeePeriodDetails.Period_Month = tblEmployeeTransactions.Period_Month 
        And tblEmployeePeriodDetails.Period_Year = tblEmployeeTransactions.Period_Year 
    ),0.0)
From 
  Employees 
Inner Join 
  tblEmployeePeriodDetails On Employees.EmployeeID = tblEmployeePeriodDetails.Employee_ID 
where 
  tblEmployeePeriodDetails.Period_Month = 7 and 
  tblEmployeePeriodDetails.Period_Year =2010
```

In my opinion the Employee has 2 records in tblEmployeeTransactions (one with PayrollCode_Code=P137 and one with another PayrollCode_Code) that's why the records are doubled.

Comment: yes actually it has more than 2 but i nid only the one with P137 in another instance I may need P115.It is a parameter or variable. @georstef

Comment: if there are no such records how could I make it 0 instead of null?Am exporting it to a csv and importing it in excel and it requires those columns to have a value?

Comment: Updated answer with the `ISNULL` function for sql-server (change to `IFNULL` if it's mysql)

Comment: yea I did lyk so ISNULL(SUM(tblEmployeeTransactions.Amount),0)